# Unchecking event ListView Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I trigger unchecking box action in a `ListView` control ? In default `ListView` events I can only see `ItemCheck` and `ItemChecked` event where is `ItemUnchecked` and `ItemUncheck`?

Comment: The same event can be used to check the state of the item (whether it is checked/unchecked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the [ItemCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked.aspx) event and read the [NewValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs.newvalue.aspx) property to determine if it's about to be checked or unchecked.

```
private void myListView_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    { 
        //unchecked
    }       
    else if(e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        //checked
    }               
}
```